# Slide div up from bottom to read more content

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

i'm trying to slide a text in from under a div. Each text has variable length. I created the following JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ronnos/5AnRk/1/

The problem here is that it slides down instead of up (the other menu-items move up). I want the other items to remain at the bottom of the page.

I know that what i've achieved so far can be easily done with just CSS and transitions:

```
.item-reader {display:none}
.menu-item:hover > .item-reader {display:block}
```

But i want to slide it up (this is another example: http://return-true.com/2010/03/creating-a-slide-up-footer-using-jquery/)

Thanks if someone will help me!

Comment: also rather of using `.slideToggle()` use `.stop().slideToggle()` check  http://jsfiddle.net/5AnRk/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5AnRk/4/

Jquery :

```
$('.menu-item').hover(
    function() { 
        $(this).children('.read-more').show();
        $(this).animate({'marginTop' : '-25px'} );
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({'marginTop' : '0px'}, function(){
            $(this).children('.read-more').hide(); 
        });
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
#menu-wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: A custom animation like this would seem to fit the bill. You can animate most properties. You might also consider a CSS3 animation if the animation is not mission critical. It will hit the user's CPU less hard.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I adjusted your code:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Ronnos/7NP22/
The only limitation is that the "read-more" link only can contain a certain amount of words because of it's fixed height. But for now i agree with it, otherwise it will be more complicater.

Thanks Again

Comment: And now i've updated everything to CSS ONLY: http://jsfiddle.net/Ronnos/9BXZ3/ Thanks again